# instargram css стили

Tags: css

Может кто хоть раз смотрел исходный код instargrama, объясните мне в чем смысл прописывать стили для элементов в таком виде, почему они не стали записывать стили в файлы? Может какое преимущество есть в таком виде, я вот его не вижу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instargram использует CSS плагин [Isostyle](https://github.com/iiegor/isostyle), который и добавляет стили в  `head`  с уникальным идентификатором (data-isostyle-id).

> С помощью Isostyle можно использовать функцию `require()` с CSS
>   и LESS файлами.

О плюсах минусах такого метода судите сами.